# Play Vimeo video in Android VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am working on an Android application. In my app I have to play videos in `VideoView`. The videos from the Vimeo is not working. Whenever I tried to load Vimeo video I am getting the error message:

```
"sorry, this video cannot be played".
```

I saw some of the similar discussions in StackOverflow. So I tried [Vittamio  demo](http://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/). There also Vimeo videos are not playing.

In the case of youtube url we have to convert to RTSP. for example

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jx3pdWBlZ34
```

will convert to

```
rtsp://v4.cache8.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQl-Z2VgdekdJxMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
```

I gave sample url is like this.

```
private String path = "http://player.vimeo.com/video/49462103 ";
and
private String path = "http://vimeo.com/49462103";
```

Is this the right way to enter Vimeo url in Android

Please help me to fix my issues friends.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this problem?, I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo provides PRO members access to their own source files via the new API3.

They are available on every video response, under the `files` key. You can get video responses by requesting a specific video (single video: `/videos/{video_id}`) or by requesting a collection of videos (your videos: `/me/videos`).

You can learn more about the api here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start

Comment: i have pro account. can you help me in getting direct link?

Comment: I updated the answer. LMK if it answers your question!

Comment: Hi @Dashron I am a Vimeo Pro user and trying to play Vimeo videos in VideoView but can't since it is a Video.link gives me a https link. Do I have to use a WebView only to play Vimeo video? Are there any other light-weight widgets available?